# Web Application Deployment Issue with Nested WEB-INF/classes Folders in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering an issue while deploying my web application. It seems that during the deployment process, multiple nested 'WEB-INF/classes' folders are being generated recursively, creating a structure like this:

WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF...

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE, and I suspect there might be a configuration issue that's causing this behavior. Could anyone suggest what might be causing this and how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please check from File | Project Structure | Project Settings | Modules, and exclude the Resource folder.